# XSLT take data before specific date

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to get data before a specific date. So any data inside the elements that are after this date should be displayed, otherwise not. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//magadvert">
    <xsl:if test="releaseDate > 2018-09-15">
        <tr>
            ...Do Something
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Data:

```
<magadvert advertID="1">
    <releaseDate>2018-06-22</releaseDate>
    <endDate>2018-09-08</endDate>
    <magName>Phasellus At Augue Industries</magName>
    <advertSize>3971.69</advertSize>
    <position>Inside front</position>
    <magCost>35217.49</magCost>
    <issuesAppeared>11</issuesAppeared>
</magadvert>
```

The type of "releaseDate" is **xs:date** in schema. Whenever I try to run this condition it returns empty result as if this condition is never met, while there are entries in the data that are after this date. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 doesn't have any recognition of dates. Doing `releaseDate > 2018-09-15` is actually the same as doing `releaseDate > 1992` (Because it is parsed as a numeric expression, and 2018 - 09 - 15 = 1992)

You could try putting it in apostrophes, like `releaseDate > '2018-09-15'` but this wouldn't work either, because string comparison is limited in XSLT 1.0, and so the `>` operator does not work on strings.

So, what you can do (in XSLT 1.0) is translate the strings to numbers (by removing the hyphens) and doing numeric comparison

```
<xsl:if test="number(translate(releaseDate, '-', '')) > 20180915">
```

Alternatively, upgrade to using an XSLT 2.0, which can handle dates, then you could do...

```
<xsl:if test="xs:date(releaseDate) > xs:date('2018-09-15')">
```

Note, as an aside, you can put the if condition in the `xsl:for-each` itself

```
<xsl:for-each select="//magadvert[number(translate(releaseDate, '-', '')) > 20180915]">
```

Comment: Complete answer. As side note: in XPath 1.0 only `=` and `!=` are defined in terms of string comparison, but in XSLT 1.0 you still can sort string (by comparison) with `xsl:sort` instruction.